# Wysiwyg with ckeditor and custom configuration

Tags: wysiwyg

Is there any way to add custom configuration to ckeditor when using through the wysiwyg module?

Using the ckeditor module there is an advanced option and there it is possible to edit that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this Denver DrupalCon2012 Talk: [What-you-see-not-always-what-you-get-it-can-be](http://denver2012.drupal.org/program/sessions/what-you-see-not-always-what-you-get-it-can-be)

Google Docs [here](http://bit.ly/ideograph-wysiwyg)